# Redirect url with specific query string to home page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I have a hacked website where a hacker has injected e-commerce pages.

The pages are ranked on google but I want to redirect them to the homepage.

They have the following URL structure. The digits are randomly generated and they are almost 1000 on SERP. I have put random digits as an example:

```
https://example.com/?itemywdy11111111.html

https://example.com/?itemywdy51111.html
```

Below is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^itemywdy$
RewriteRule (.*) / [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The code above is not working at all.

How do I do a 301 redict using htaccess for these urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should match only the starting part of query string leaving end anchor:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)itemywdy [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Also note use of `(?:^|&)` to let this string match anywhere in a query string which would allow this rule to work for your existing pages with other query strings as well.